# Java Swing problems in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface

I used Netbeans a lot but recently switched to Eclipse Luna.  I am trying to create a GUI app in Java but I am having some trouble with this.
The drag and drop of Swing is very restrictive in Eclipse, I can get the label or text field any where on the screen I want, it keeps snapping to these weird "grid lines", or am I doing something wrong?

Are there extra plugins I need or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you're talking about WindowBuilder, I believe there's an option to disable snap to grid.

Comment: And check you current layout manager.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html

Comment: The snap to grid doesn't work for me.  If you ever used Netbeans and designed GUI with it you know how easy it is to place components.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem.  I had to change the type of layout my form uses.
Thanks for your help.